# StackExchange.Redis + Azure Redis inconsistent speeds

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I am using Azure Redis and StackExchange.Redis in order to provide Twitter like news feed. And this  is happening to me:

I publish code to my Cloud Service, and everything is working great, page with 60 feed items loads in less than 300 ms which is awesome for me. And this works for a while, lets say for a couple of hours, then loading of feed page slows down to around 8000 ms.

Strange thing is that when I'm testing same code on localhost, it is consistently fast at around 500 ms. I am connected to same Redis instance, which is in US, and I'm in Europe (and Cloud Service and Redis are in same Azure region -  East US).

Trough Azue portal I can see that Redis Server load is below 10% at all times, and CPU usage is below 40%. Because of this and good speed loads on localhost I believe that there isn't any problem with Redis, and obviously I am doing something stupid in my code and I cannot see it, so here is my code:

Here is how I'm initializing my connection to Redis:

```
  public static class AzureRedisFeedsConnectionMultiplexer
{
    private static readonly Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> LazyConnection =
       new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(
           () =>
           {
               var config = new ConfigurationOptions
               {
                   AbortOnConnectFail = false,
                   Password = password,
                   EndPoints = { "myEndpoint" },
                   ConnectRetry = 5,
                   ConnectTimeout = 2 * 60 * 1000,
                   Ssl = true
               };

               return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(config);
           });

    private static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
    {
        get { return LazyConnection.Value; }
    }

    public static ConnectionMultiplexer GetRedisConnection()
    {
        return Connection;
    }

    public static IDatabase GetRedisDatabase()
    {
        return Connection.GetDatabase();
    }
}
```

Here is API call (which calls my FeedService):

```
  public async Task<List<FeedMobileHelper>> GetFeedForAllUsers(int page, int pageSize, int skip, int take)
    {
        return
            await
                _feedService.GetFeedWorkoutsFromRedisAsync(AzureRedisFeedsConnectionMultiplexer.GetRedisDatabase(),
                    User.Identity.GetUserId(), (page - 1)*pageSize, pageSize - 1);
    }
```

Here is this method in FeedService:

```
public async Task<List<FeedMobileHelper>> GetFeedWorkoutsFromRedisAsync(IDatabase redis, string userId, int numOfItemsToSkip, int numOfItemsToTake)
    {

        var redisFeed = await redis.ListRangeAsync("FeedAllWorkouts", numOfItemsToSkip, numOfItemsToSkip + numOfItemsToTake);

        /* WE KNOW FOR SURE TAHT THERE IS 10.000  ELEMENTS IN FEED SOTRED IN REDIS*/
        //so if there is request for more (i.e. already gotten (numOfItemsToSkip) +  numOfItemsToTake > 10.000 go to SQL

        if (numOfItemsToSkip + numOfItemsToTake > 10000)
        {
            //some items arealready fetched from redis, so we have to skip those
            var numOfItemsToGet = numOfItemsToSkip + numOfItemsToTake - 10000;
            return await GetFeedWorkoutsMobileAsync(numOfItemsToSkip, numOfItemsToGet, userId);
        }

        // if length is zero go to SQL
        if (redisFeed.Length <= 0)
        {
            return await GetFeedWorkoutsMobileAsync(numOfItemsToSkip, numOfItemsToSkip, userId);
        }

        return await CreateRedisFeedViewModelAsync(redisFeed, redis, userId);

    }
```

I wanted to add that going to SQL (i.e. calling method GetFeedWorkoutsMobileAsync) never happens, so FeedItems are always fetched from Redis. And in Redis they are stored as list of serialized objects.

Now here is CreateRedisFeedViewModelAsync:

```
        private async Task<List<FeedMobileHelper>> CreateRedisFeedViewModelAsync(RedisValue[] redisFeed, IDatabase redis, string userId)
    {
        // data to return
        var listToReturn = new List<FeedMobileHelper>();
        // feed in redis is serialized, we have to deserialize it 
        var feedDeserialized = new RedisFeedItemWorkout[redisFeed.Length];
        // list of all workout ids that are needed for this feed page
        var workoutIds = new string[redisFeed.Length];
        //list of alll user ids needed for this feed page
        var userIds = new string[redisFeed.Length];
        var redisFeedService = new RedisFeedService();

        using (var databaseContext = new MadBarzDatabaseContext())
        {
            // go to data from redis, deserialize everything, and allso fetch necessary ids
            for (int i = 0; i < redisFeed.Length; i++)
            {
                var feedItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RedisFeedItemWorkout>(redisFeed[i]);
                feedDeserialized[i] = feedItem;
                workoutIds[i] = feedItem.WorkoutId;
                userIds[i] = feedItem.UserId;
            }

            //go to redis and fetch data about users and workouts, idea here is that we don't go to redis seperately for each user, but we fetch data for all users
            //and workouts needed to create this feed page 
            // long live redis pipeling  
            var redisFeedData = await redisFeedService.GetDataForFeed(redis, userId, workoutIds, userIds);


            var workoutsFromRedis = redisFeedData.Workouts;
            var usersFromRedis = redisFeedData.Users;
            var commentsFromRedis = redisFeedData.Comments;

            // in this for loop I just map and connect everything and if needed (i.e. if I don't get data from redis) I go and fetch data from SQL
            // that almost never happens 
            for (int i = 0; i < feedDeserialized.Length; i++)
            {
                RedisWorkoutItem workout;
                bool hasRespected;
                string username, fullName, profilePic;

                var userRedis = usersFromRedis[i];
                var stringWorkout = workoutsFromRedis[i];
                var workoutComment = commentsFromRedis[i].HasValue ? commentsFromRedis[i].ToString() : "";

                if (userRedis != null)
                {
                    profilePic = userRedis["ProfilePhotoUrl"].HasValue
                        ? userRedis["ProfilePhotoUrl"].ToString()
                        : "";
                    fullName = userRedis["FirstName"] + " " + userRedis["LastName"];
                    username = userRedis["UserName"].HasValue ? userRedis["UserName"].ToString() : "";

                }
                else
                {
                    var user = databaseContext.Users.Find(feedDeserialized[i].UserId);
                    profilePic = user.ProfilePhotoUrl;
                    username = user.UserName;
                    fullName = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName;
                }

                if (stringWorkout.HasValue)
                {
                    workout = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RedisWorkoutItem>(stringWorkout);
                    hasRespected = workout.UsersWhoRespected.Contains(userId);
                }
                else
                {
                    var workoutGuid = Guid.Parse(feedDeserialized[i].WorkoutId);

                    var workoutFromDb = await databaseContext.Trenings.FindAsync(workoutGuid);
                    var routine = await databaseContext.AllRoutineses.FindAsync(workoutFromDb.AllRoutinesId);
                    workout = new RedisWorkoutItem
                    {
                        Name = routine.Name,
                        Id = workoutFromDb.TreningId.ToString(),
                        Comment = workoutFromDb.UsersCommentOnWorkout,
                        DateWhenFinished = workoutFromDb.DateTimeWhenTreningCreated,
                        NumberOfRespects = workoutFromDb.NumberOfLikes,
                        NumberOfComments = workoutFromDb.NumberOfComments,
                        UserId = workoutFromDb.UserId,
                        Length = workoutFromDb.LengthInSeconds,
                        Points = workoutFromDb.Score


                    };

                    workoutComment = workoutFromDb.UsersCommentOnWorkout;


                    hasRespected = databaseContext.TreningRespects
                        .FirstOrDefault(r => r.TreningId == workoutGuid && r.UserId == userId) != null;
                }

                string workoutLength;

                if (workout.Length >= 3600)
                {
                    var t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(workout.Length);
                    workoutLength = $"{t.Hours:D2}:{t.Minutes:D2}:{t.Seconds:D2}";


                }
                else
                {
                    var t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(workout.Length);
                    workoutLength = $"{t.Minutes:D2}:{t.Seconds:D2}";

                }


                listToReturn.Add(new FeedMobileHelper
                {
                    Id = feedDeserialized[i].Id.ToString(),
                    UserId = workout.UserId,
                    WorkoutId = feedDeserialized[i].WorkoutId,
                    Points = workout.Points.ToString("N0", new NumberFormatInfo
                    {
                        NumberGroupSizes = new[] { 3 },
                        NumberGroupSeparator = "."
                    }),
                    WorkoutName = workout.Name,
                    WorkoutLength = workoutLength,
                    NumberOfRespects = workout.NumberOfRespects,
                    NumberOfComments = workout.NumberOfComments,
                    WorkoutComment = workoutComment,
                    HasRespected = hasRespected,
                    UserImageUrl = profilePic,
                    UserName = username,
                    DisplayName = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fullName) ? username : fullName,
                    TimeStamp = workout.DateWhenFinished,
                    DateFormatted = workout.DateWhenFinished.FormatDateToHrsDaysWeeksString()
                });
            }
        }

        return listToReturn;
    }
```

I believe that in this method lies problem, but I cannot identify  it:

```
public async Task<RedisFeedDataModel> GetDataForFeed(IDatabase redisDb, string userId, string[] workoutIds, string[] userIds)
    {
        var listOfUsers = new Task<HashEntry[]>[userIds.Length];
        var workoutsToReturn = new List<RedisValue>();
        var usersToReturn = new List<Dictionary<RedisValue, RedisValue>>();
        var commentsToReturn = new List<RedisValue>();
        var listOfTaks = new List<Task<RedisValue>>();


        for (var i = 0; i < userIds.Length; i++)
        {
            listOfTaks.Add(redisDb.StringGetAsync("workout:" + workoutIds[i]));
            listOfTaks.Add(redisDb.StringGetAsync("workoutComment:" + workoutIds[i]));
            listOfUsers[i] = redisDb.HashGetAllAsync("user:" + userIds[i]);
        }

        var resultForListOfTasks =  await Task.WhenAll(listOfTaks);
        var resultForListOfUsers = await Task.WhenAll(listOfUsers);

        for (var i = 0; i < resultForListOfTasks.Length; i += 2)
        {
            workoutsToReturn.Add(resultForListOfTasks[i]);
            commentsToReturn.Add( resultForListOfTasks[i + 1]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < resultForListOfUsers.Length; i++)
        {

            var redisUser = resultForListOfUsers[i];
            var userToReturn = redisUser.Length > 0 ? redisUser.ToDictionary(t => t.Name, t => t.Value) : null;
            usersToReturn.Add(userToReturn);
        }


        return new RedisFeedDataModel
        {
            Comments = commentsToReturn,
            Workouts = workoutsToReturn,
            Users = usersToReturn

        };

    }
```

Funny thing is that when call for feed slows down on production, if I try same call with same data to same RedisDB on localhost, it is much faster than on production (for example on production it lasts 8000ms and on localhost it takes 500 ms)

Comment: hyperN, did you find out what was wrong?

Comment: TBH I cannot remember anymore - it was long time ago :(
But we are still using Redis in PROD and we are pretty happy with it, I quickly checked similar endpoint  and now I am getting consistent speeds